# How to hide the asp-for label element if the value of displayfor element is empty?

Tags: html, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

In my cshtml class for details, I do need to disable the label(asp-for) if the value of displayfor is empty.

```
@*For simplicity I put only part of the code as everything below is pretty much the same piece of code *@
<div align="center">
<div class="media-middle" style="width: 600px;">
    <table class="table glyphicon-align-center">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th><label asp-for="StrainName"></label></th>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.StrainName)</td>
            </tr>
```

I would be thankful if someone gives me  an idea  about how to realize this code and where it is better to implement the code( cshtml class or in a controller)

Comment: why would you disable a label ? What is the point of doing that ?

Comment: If you want to hide, just do an if condition to conditionally render the label.

Comment: also, hide!=disable. Please provide clear "expected behavior" in the question.

Comment: Do you want to disable or hide when element is empty? Do you have any issue with implementing the suggestion from @Shyju that add if condition for `<td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.StrainName)</td>`?

Comment: First of all, thank you guys for the quick response. The exact behavior that I expecting is when the value of DisplayFor is empty(null), then the label asp-for... is hidden. It is supposed to implement the condition if but I don't have the experience yet.